# Oracle DBMS_SCHEDULER_LOGGING_OFF

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, dbms-scheduler

I've defined a DBMS_SCHEDULER job with the logging defined to DBMS_SCHEDULER_LOGGING_OFF, as you can see in the picture:

[image]

nevertheless, when I query the DB

```
SELECT * from USER_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS  ORDER BY LOG_DATE DESC
```

I got all the Job details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What job class does the job belong to? While you may have defined the job with DBMS_SCHEDULER_LOGGING_OFF, if the `logging_level` of the job class that the job belongs to is higher, then Oracle will put precedence on the job class `logging_level` over the individual job's `logging_level`.

To fix this, you can either: 1. Create a new job class with the desired `logging_level`, then re-create the job using that job class, or 2. Change the `logging_level` of the existing job class by using `DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_attribute`. I would recommend creating a new job class, as changing the existing job class would probably result in undesired results.

To create a new job class with logging off, your code would look something like:

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB_CLASS (
   job_class_name => 'mytestjobclass',
   logging_level => DBMS_SCHEDULER.LOGGING_OFF);
END;
```

If the job already belongs to its own job class and you just want to change the logging level, your code would look something like this:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE (
   name => 'mytestjobclass', 
   attribute => 'logging_level', 
   value => DBMS_SCHEDULER.LOGGING_OFF);
END;
```

You can find more info on job classes and `logging_level` here: [29.8.2.3 Precedence of Logging Levels in Jobs and Job Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/scheduse.htm#ADMIN12384).